# Import properties @Value on Spring batch Test

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-batch, junit5

I have this case:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${batch.cron-rule}")    
public void perform() throws Exception {
     JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters();
     jobLauncher.run(jobRegistry.getJob("idemOperationJob"), jobParameters);
}
```

and in my test I have to import that property `batch.cron-rule` when it starts the job.
I create a file `application-test.properties` in `src/test/resources` with this parameter and in test I set this annotation

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = LoadJob.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
class LoadJobTest {
```

but it seams not work.

Environment is JUnit 5.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
```

Or

```
 @PropertySource("classpath*:application-test.properties")
```

Or

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = {
   "classpath:application-test.properties"})
```

Let us know if none of above works for you.